# Porting python aes ecb to php openssl

Tags: python, php, openssl, aes, ecb

I have python code

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES


def pad(data):
    block_size = 16
    bytes_to_add = block_size - ((len(data) % block_size) or block_size)
    return data + (b'\0' * bytes_to_add)


cipher = AES.new(b"4452038393672345", AES.MODE_ECB)
body = pad("asa masa".encode('utf-8'))
content = base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(body)).decode('ascii')
```

I see result "sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwg=="

I want to port python code to php using openssl

```
function pad($data) {
  $block_size = 16;
  $bytes_to_add = $block_size - ((strlen($data) % $block_size) ?: $block_size);
  return $data . str_repeat("\0", $bytes_to_add);
}


$cipher = "AES-128-ECB";
$options = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA;
$plainText = pad("asa masa");
$key = '4452038393672345';
$encryptedText = openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, $options);
$encodedText = base64_encode($encryptedText);
```

I see result from openssl "c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3dWZPTjExZ21iUG1VQUI0c0EwaktVaz0="

Another code in php

```
$rawData = openssl_encrypt(pad("asa masa"), 'AES-128-ECB', '4452038393672345');
```

return "sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwufON11gmbPmUAB4sA0jKUk="

If anyone is interested, do it this way and everything is fine

```
If anyone is interested, do it this way and everything is fine
$encrypted = openssl_encrypt(pad("asa masa"), 'AES-128-ECB', '4452038393672345',OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING);
$encrypted=base64_encode($encrypted);
```

Result is "sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwg=="

Thanks

Comment: You edited your original question and answered it yourself. Self-answering is fine, but the correct way would be to post a *separate* answer.

Comment: Your answer is also not quite right: The actual cause of the problem is a double Base64 encoding (default and explicit) and a double padding (custom Zero padding plus the default PKCS#7 padding). The fix is to disable one of the Base64 encodings (e.g. the default encoding via `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`) and likewise the default PKCS#7 padding (via `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`). `OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY` is not required at all.

Answer (score -2):

if we refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-encrypt.php

> options is a bitwise disjunction of the flags OPENSSL_RAW_DATA and OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING.

OPENSSL_RAW_DATA = 1 (binary: `01`)
OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING = 2 (binary: `10`)

so:

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 0)); // 00 = no flags
c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3dWZPTjExZ21iUG1VQUI0c0EwaktVaz0=

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 1)); // 01 = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA
sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwufON11gmbPmUAB4sA0jKUk=

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 2)); // 10 = OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3Zz09

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 3)); // 11 = OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING
sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwg==
```

and the pattern repeats since we're only looking for last 2 bits

```
base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 4)); // (1)00
c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3dWZPTjExZ21iUG1VQUI0c0EwaktVaz0=

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 5)); // (1)01
sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwufON11gmbPmUAB4sA0jKUk=

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 6)); // (1)10
c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3Zz09

base64_encode(openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 7)); // (1)11
sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwg==
```

OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_DONT_ZERO_PAD_KEY | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING = 1 | 4 | 2 = 7
so we get `openssl_encrypt($plainText, $cipher, $key, 7)`

by default `openssl_encrypt` uses `PKCS#7` padding which causes "double padding" (your zero pad + PKCS) that's why in you should use OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING in your case (it's recommended to use default `openssl_encrypt` padding)

if you visit https://www.base64decode.org/ you can see that
`c0VQNVJDV21kUWRQWW8vZWVXVkl3dWZPTjExZ21iUG1VQUI0c0EwaktVaz0=` is base64 encoded `sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwufON11gmbPmUAB4sA0jKUk=`
and `sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwufON11gmbPmUAB4sA0jKUk=` is just `sEP5RCWmdQdPYo/eeWVIwg==` with some additional stuff caused by double padding